# Is there a way I can load a cursor without restarting or logging out?

Tags: c++, windows

I want to load a cursor without restart of log off from the computer.

I have tried to use `LoadCursorFromFile` function but it not working.

Is there other ways to load a cursor ?

EDIT: I have also tried to use `SetCursor` function but it still not working.

Here is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <lmcons.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")  

using namespace std;

string username()
{
    char username[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD username_len = UNLEN + 1;
    GetUserName(username, &username_len);
    return username;
}

int main()
{
    string dir = "C:\\Users\\" + username() + "\\Documents\\Dragonite";
    string dwnld_URL = "https://srv-file7.gofile.io/download/2rNCim/nat927.ani";
    string savepath = "C:\\Users\\" + username() + "\\Documents\\Dragonite\\nyan.ani";

    CreateDirectory(dir.c_str(), NULL);

    URLDownloadToFile(NULL, dwnld_URL.c_str(), savepath.c_str(), 0, NULL);

    Sleep(5000);

    HCURSOR hCur = LoadCursorFromFile(savepath.c_str());
    SetCursor(hCur);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You've almost certainly done exactly that with the code you show. What think you're failing to appreciate is that `SetCursor` is not a System-Wide call. That is to say, calling it only changes the cursor while it's hovering a window of your own application. Since the last thing your app does before exiting is set the cursor, you'll never see the affect. ;) I suggest reviewing carefully the **Remarks** section found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursor

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks, What can i do to make it  work like i want ?

Comment: @MrStrings - I hardly do any WinAPI stuff anymore. From vague memory, it's related to theming and is likely undocumented or actively discouraged.

Comment: @enhzflep My program is now working! I will post answer soon.

Comment: @enhzflep I have posted an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done my project and it is now working, special thanks to @enhzflep

I have changed `SetCursor` function to `SetSystemCursor`.

*Note - For an application to use any of the OCR_ constants, you must to `#define OEMRESOURCE` before including the `Windows.h` library!

```
#include <iostream>

#define OEMRESOURCE 100

#include <Windows.h>
#include <lmcons.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")  

using namespace std;

string username()
{
    char username[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD username_len = UNLEN + 1;
    GetUserName(username, &username_len);
    return username;
}

int main()
{
    string dir = "C:\\Users\\" + username() + "\\Documents\\Dragonite";
    string dwnld_URL = "https://srv-file7.gofile.io/download/2rNCim/nat927.ani";
    string savepath = "C:\\Users\\" + username() + "\\Documents\\Dragonite\\nyan.ani";

    CreateDirectory(dir.c_str(), NULL);

    URLDownloadToFile(NULL, dwnld_URL.c_str(), savepath.c_str(), 0, NULL);

    HCURSOR hCUR = LoadCursorFromFile(savepath.c_str());
    SetSystemCursor(hCUR, OCR_NORMAL);

    if (!SetSystemCursor) {
        cout << GetLastError();
    }
    return 0;
}
```